# Zebra Scanner Adding Newline

Tags: c#, xamarin, barcode-scanner, datawedge

I'm using a Zebra TC70 with DataWedge to capture scanned data. Every barcode I scan is having \r\n appended to the end.

Why is it doing this and how can I stop it?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: This is not a programming problem.  Read the instruction manual for your device and disable this feature.

Comment: @Jason I don't see anything in the user manual about adding a newline to scanning

Comment: Chapter 4 of the Integrators Guide, "DataWedge Configuration"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use any barcode reader, they usually come with a manual which include configurations. Like what characters should include after the reading.

For your particular scanner you can check [this](https://www.libertysystems.com/about/resources/automatic-carriage-return-for-zebra-mobile-computers/)

The characters \r\n are escape characters indicating a new line.

Sometimes it's there, sometimes it's not, depending on the configuration of the reader.

If it bothers you, you can always replace the unwanted characters by empty characters

```
string myInput;
myInput=myInput.Replace("\r\n","");
```

`myInput.Trim("\r\n".ToCharArray())` or `TrimEnd` are other alternatives